# Jenkins uDeploy failure

Tags: jenkins, udeploy

After creating a tar of the build from jenkins, I am trying to move the tar to the main server using uDeploy. But i get the following error even after using the proper application name, environment and process name. I am unable to debug any further.

Please find the uDeploy settings and the log in the images.

uDeploy Jenkins setup:
[image]

error in console:
[image]

Comment: Please post your code it will be easy to understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, have you done this workaround

- Open jenkins.war and navigate to META-INF
- Delete JENKINS.SF and JENKINS.RSA
- Open MANIFEST.MF and delete all of the lines that start with SHA1-Digest
- Place the new Log4j with version greater or equal to 1.2.12 (e.g. Log4J 1.2.17) jar in WEB-INF/lib
- Update MANIFEST.MF to point to the new version